# How can I modify <style> element in phpMyAdmin login form?

Tags: php, css, phpmyadmin

I wanted to change background image on phpMyAdmin login page (index.php), but I have no idea how I'm supposed to do it. I tried to add `<style>` elements by echoing them in `/phpmyadmin/libraries/plugins/auth/AuthenticationCookie.php` file, but it adds items after `<body>` tag.

Comment: https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/themes.html

Comment: @Phil Thank you for the idea, I wasn't considering themes as a possible solution, since every change I've made on the login form was in the AuthenticationCookie.php file. I'll try to modify pmahomme theme later and I'll share the results with you.

Comment: phpmyadmin is made of a couple of divs covering the main bg so you need to check the specific div you want to change the background image of and add your style to that

Comment: @KevinGales The login form is in <body id='loginform'>, and that's what I was looking for in common.css.php. I'm going to provide you with the answer, since I've found it few minutes ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Phil I've managed to modify `/phpmyadmin/themes/pmahomme/css/common.css.php` file, and I've found where I can change the CSS code to properly add a background picture to the login form. In my file it was placed on lines 871-875:

```css
body#loginform {
    margin-top: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url("<file>");
}
```